# Writing large file causes UI to freeze for a short time in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pptxgenjs

I have a button that generate powerpoint slides onClick, but the screen is frozen for ~1 seconds during the generation process, here is the flow:

(1). user clicks on the button

(2). turn on the spinner by `setIsGenerating(true)` to signal that the generation is in progress

(3). fire async requests to fetch image data in base64 format

(4). used nested loop to insert slides of images and text

(5). `writeFile().then(()=> setIsGenerating(false))`   is executed to download and stop the spinner. **By reading my console log, the freeze starts right before writeFile(),which already returns a promise. Commenting out writeFile() does remove the freeze problem , but this function is mandatory**

(6) One more problem is that download started ~1 second after spinner is disappear, but I expect the download to start at the same time as spinner disappear

(7) The downloaded file is ~120,000 KB, which does not seem so large to my eyes , but the performance is bad for some reasons that I don't know

**CreatePPT function**

```
    const createPPT = async () => {
        setIsGenerating(true)
        let cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart')) || []
        let pres = new pptxgen();
        let newCart = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(cart))
        const imgList = []
        await Promise.all(newCart.map(async (d) => {
            if (d.img !== "") {
                let result = await axios.get(d.img, {
                    responseType: 'arraybuffer'
                })
                let image = Buffer.from(result.data, 'binary').toString('base64')
                image = `data:image/jpg;base64,${image}`
                imgList.push(image)
            }
        }))
        newCart.map((d, i) => {

            if (d.img !== "") {

                d.img = imgList[i]
                return d
            }
        })
        newCart.map(d => {
            let slide = pres.addSlide()
            d.img && slide.addImage({ data: d.img, w: "100%", sizing: { type: "crop" } });
            slide.addText(d.title, { x: '0', y: '0', w: '100%', h: '20%', align: 'center', valign: 'middle', color: "ffffff", });
            slide.background = { color: "#000000" };
            d.content.map(text => {
                let slide_2 = pres.addSlide();
                d.img && slide_2.addImage({
                    data: d.img,
                    w: "100%",
                    sizing: {
                        type: "crop"
                    }
                });
                slide_2.addText(text, { x: '0', y: '0', w: '100%', h: '20%', align: 'center', valign: 'middle', color: "ffffff", })
                slide_2.background = { color: "#000000" };
            })
        })


//This writeFile() function seems to cause UI to freeze for a short time
        pres.writeFile({ fileName: "Sample Presentation.pptx" })
            .then(() => {
                setIsGenerating(false)
            })
    }
```

**Button**

```
<Button onClick={createPPT}> Create PPT </Button>
```

Comment: You may try to comment out each part to figure out which part causes the freeze, then wrap that part in a promise.

Comment: The freeze starts right before writeFile(), this function already returns a promise. If I comment out writeFile(), the freeze does disappear, but this function is mandatory